# Google Places Autocomple API Access Denied/Requires API Key

Tags: java, apache, google-places-api

Edit (Answer): KEY is case sensitive. I was using `Key` instead of `key`

I am creating a simple HTTP request to google places autocomplete api but I am getting an error 
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

```
Code: 200
Response: OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   "error_message" : "This service requires an API key.",
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
```

My Key is enabled and live is related to "Google Places API Web Service".

Here is my sample code. What I am doing wrong?

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class GoogleAPI {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

        URI uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("https")
                .setHost("maps.googleapis.com")
                .setPath("maps/api/place/autocomplete/json")
                .setParameter("input", "London")
                .setParameter("Key", "*********")
                .build();

        HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(uri);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getMethod);

        System.out.println("Code: " +   response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        System.out.println(("Response: ")+  response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase() );
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(responseString);



    }

}
```

I have hid my key.

Comment: Url parameters are case sensitive. Can you try `key` instead of `Key`?

Comment: Worked: Thank you.